# Is it possible to use the Messages app with Google Voice?

Tags: iphone, messages

I've got an iPhone 4 that has no mobile plan or phone number, but I've got a Google Voice account. I know I can use the Google Voice app to communicate over SMS, but is it possible to configure the built in Messages app to use the Google Voice number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android, i know you can set the google voice, and/or hangouts(which is better version of google voice), to divert all texts to the native sms app. but i dont think you can with apple messages. they are so strict and guarding of using imessage for anything else but apple use, so i seriously doubt it. but try hangouts. its just like using a normal phone. and you can check the settings in it and see if it'll do it. yup. you can even facetime in hangouts! haha.